# If element has class, apply class to body

Tags: javascript

I have a website where each section displays as a full screen panel.
I would like to style all the other elements on the page according to what panel is displaying.
For example, if the panel with the class `.style-reality-green-bg` is active, I would like to style the navigation and other items to compliment the green.

Currently when you scroll, the full screen panel has a constant class called .onepage-section. When you scroll between panels, a second class is added depending on which panel is currently on screen.
This is handled by the theme, but I set the panel classes

At the moment I have a few sections which have classes such as...

```
.style-reality-green-bg
.style-rebel-red-bg
.style-rethink-blue-bg
```

I can't style all the elements I need to because they are not children of these panels so I was trying to find a way to add the same class to the body when each panel was active. So - if `.onepage-section` has a class of `.style-reality-green-bg` add the class `.style-reality-green-bg` to the body as well.

I have done some digging but I can mostly only find examples for 'click' actions

My latest attempt is

```
if ($('.onepage-section').hasClass('style-reality-green-bg')) {
    $(this)body().addClass('style-reality-green-bg');
}
```

But it just returns an error saying

> $ is not a function

****** EDIT

To clarify

What I am trying to achieve is...

If the full screen container has a class of

```
.onepage-section
```

AND a class of

```
.style-reality-green-bg
```

add

```
.style-reality-green-bg
```

to the body, and so on

I'm not sure if that was clear

Comment: Are you using `jQuery` ?`$` is often seen in Jquery application, but it is not a native JavaScript function; if you are not using jQuery, use `document.querySelector` instead. Also, I think it should be a dot beween `this` and `body()`: ` $(this).body()` . IMO it is quite rare to use `jQuery` nowadays

Answer (score 0):

The reference to `body` seems malformed, the code should be

```
if ($('.onepage-section').hasClass('style-reality-green-bg')) {
    $('body').addClass('style-reality-green-bg');
}
```

if `$` is still undefined, do you have jQuery included? https://jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your error means that you dont include the external Jquery Library. You can use for example a cdn to include jquery. Add this line above your closing body tag. Good would be to inlcude jquery before your Jquery command is calling.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Hi there

I have this in my source code?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ww1t45evvq97k23/Screenshot%202022-03-18%20at%204.11.22%20pm.png?dl=0

Thanks so much for your help

Comment: @MrToad Ok i see theat you already included JQuery in your DOM. Then you have take care what i wrote at last in my answer. JQuery must already initialised before the interpreter come to your code. You can try this: Put the JQuery script tag in your head.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use jQuery but haven't imported the library. For that, see https://jquery.com/download/

Additionally, in your code snippet you should select the body with `$('body')`.

Alternatively, if you want to use vanilla JavaScript, you can use the following snippet:

```js
if (document.querySelector('.onepage-section').classList.contains('style-reality-green-bg')) {
  document.body.classList.add('style-reality-green-bg');
}
```

For information on `classList`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: Hi there

When I look at my source code i can see this - is this not it?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ww1t45evvq97k23/Screenshot%202022-03-18%20at%204.11.22%20pm.png?dl=0

Thanks in advance

Comment: I did try that Vanilla JS but unfortunately it doesn't appear to be working. Thanks!

Comment: From your screenshot it looks like you should have jQuery available. If you open your website with your browser dev tools and go to the JavaScript console, what is the output when you type `typeof $`?

Comment: Why does the vanilla js not work? Is there an error?

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)body()` doesn't exists. Better write this instead:

```
if ($('.onepage-section').hasClass('style-reality-green-bg')) {
    $('body').addClass('style-reality-green-bg');
}
```

And rememer to include jquery library.